# How to configure IIS 10 to read from local SQL database file?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis-10, connection-strings

I have been trying to deploy original ASP .NET Web Application using MVC template with authentication via a local SQL database file. So far, I am able to get it to work on my computer. When I publish it to a folder on a remote server, I can't seem to figure out how to configure IIS 10 to read from that local SQL database file saved to its App_Data subdirectory. I have been getting the following error as a result:

> SQL Network Interfaces error 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.

I attempt to fix the problem by installing SQL Server 2012 Express on the remote server, but the problem is still there. So I figure the problem might be coming from the connection string:

> Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20180923034052.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20180923034052;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient

The above is what I have on my computer. Since I configure the SQL server as default on the remote server, I figure that I should match up the name of SQL server database engine, which is MSSQLSERVER by default as shown below. It didn't work neither.

> Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20180923034052.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20180923034052;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient

What configuration am I missing to get this simple ASP .NET web application to work?

Comment: You simply wrote the wrong connection string, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 LocalDB and SQL Server Express have their own patterns, while `.\MSSQLSERVER` is for something else.

Comment: Thanks. That leads me onto the right path. Apparently, installing SQL Server 2012 is pointless. I just need to install SQL Server LocalDB, a separate installation from the main one. Afterward, I need to configure the Application Pool to use the Local System as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737373/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-4-application-using-localdb-to-local-iis-on-windows-7). After that, it works fine with the original connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the default connection string that is created with the project to work, you would need to install **SQL Server LocalDB** on the remote server. It is a separate installation from the main one. Here is the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) to where you can download **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 LocalDB**.

Afterward, setup the directory to where the project is published to use the **Local System** as its application pool via **IIS Manager**. To do this as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737373/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-4-application-using-localdb-to-local-iis-on-windows-7):

1. Click on **Application Pools** in **IIS Manager**.
2. Click on **Add Application Pool...** to create a new application pool. Use whatever setting and name you desire.
3. With the new application pool selected, click on **Advanced Settings...** and change the **Identity** to **Local System** by clicking on **...**. It is found in the pull-down menu under **Built-in account**.
4. Click **OK** to save and close all pop up windows and return back to **IIS Manager**.
5. Select your directory to where the project is published to and click on **Advanced Settings...**.
6. Change **Application Pool** to the newly created application pool and click **OK** to finish.

Please note that it is not practical to keep the **application pool** running as **Local System** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ), but it is sufficient for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was to add the appool as a user to SQL Server.
Namely, at the SQL Server level, go to security. Add new login.
Add IIS APPPOOL\APPPOOLNAME as a user. Do not do check user or anything. Accept defaults and add the appool user to SQL Server. Give this user the read/write permissions on the database and that's it.
[MSDN BLOG reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/)